# How to get SVG map province, district, title attributes Using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How to get the attributes values from SVG Map path. I used javascript

```
    
    <object data="https://svgur.com/i/QXQ.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="map"></object>
        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("map");
            a.addEventListener("load",function(){
                var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
                var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("provinceMap");

                delta.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
                    console.log(e["path"]);
                }, false);
            }, false);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can

```
console.log(e['path'][0].getAttribute("province"));
console.log(e['path'][0].getAttribute("district"));
console.log(e['path'][0].getAttribute("title"));
```